# SQL @Local_Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, local-variables

Does anyone know why my variables aren't working

```
DECLARE @AmountOfDaysBooked int
DECLARE @TempHolRemaining int
SET     @AmountOfDaysBooked = (DATEDIFF(D,@StartDate, @EndDate)-1),
        @TempHolRemaining = ((  
        SELECT HolidaysRemaining
        FROM Employees
        WHERE ID = @EmployeeID) - @AmountOfDaysBooked)
```

I'm receiving this error

Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spHolBookingForm, Line 6
Must declare the table variable "@AmountOfDaysBooked".
Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spHolBookingForm, Line 8
Must declare the table variable "@TempHolRemaining".

Comment: Lose the line `UPDATE  @TempHolRemaining`, since your variable isn't a table that line doesn't make any sense, then try it again.

Comment: I know I was testing it didn't change it back,
Now its been changed i'm recieving
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spHolBookingForm, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ','.

    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spHolBookingForm, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '-'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change change your above code as below and test

```
DECLARE @AmountOfDaysBooked int
DECLARE @TempHolRemaining int
SET     @AmountOfDaysBooked = (DATEDIFF(D,@StartDate, @EndDate)-1)
SELECT @TempHolRemaining = HolidaysRemaining - @AmountOfDaysBooked
FROM Employees
WHERE ID = @EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE  @table1 table  ( AmountOfDaysBooked int)
DECLARE  @table2 table  ( TempHolRemaining int)
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

UPDATE  @table1
SET     AmountOfDaysBooked = (DATEDIFF(D,@StartDate, @EndDate)-1)
UPDATE  @table2 
SET     TempHolRemaining = ((  
        SELECT HolidaysRemaining
        FROM Employees 
        WHERE ID = @EmployeeID) - (SELECT AmountOfDaysBooked from @table1))
```